# Cor desse menu em android studio

Tags: javascript, android

Olá, alguem me ajuda a colocar a cor preta nos textos? parece que está branca, ou transparente.Não estou achando onde é, obrigado.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<data />

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/map_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.arlib.floatingsearchview.FloatingSearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_place"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:floatingSearch_close_search_on_keyboard_dismiss="true"
                app:floatingSearch_dimBackground="true"
                app:floatingSearch_leftActionMode="showHamburger"
                app:floatingSearch_menu="@menu/search_view"
                app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginLeft="8dp"
                app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginRight="8dp"
                app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginTop="8dp"
                app:floatingSearch_showSearchKey="false"
                app:floatingSearch_searchHint=""
                app:floatingSearch_suggestionsListAnimDuration="250" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/search_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/search_default"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="150dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>
            </com.arlib.floatingsearchview.FloatingSearchView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_pickup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/marker_pickup"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_destination"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/marker_destination"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_confirm_pickup"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:text="@string/confirm_pickup_location"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/button_confirm_destination"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:text="@string/confirm_destination_location"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
            app:layout_behavior="com.innomalist.taxi.common.components.WABottomSheetBehavior">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/time"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/time"
                    android:text="@string/pickup_time"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:onClick="onSelectTimeClicked"/>
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_request"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                    android:text="@string/confirm_service_empty"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button_time"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
                <com.innomalist.taxi.common.components.WrapContentViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/service_types_view_pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:clipToPadding="true"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_request"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_categories"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    <!app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/service_types_view_pager"/>
                    tools:context=".activities.main.MainActivityOld">

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Poste seu código (XML)

Comment: ``android:textColor="#000000"`` basta adicionar isso ao xml do textView

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar um `android:textColor="#000000"` para alterar a cor da fonte, esse código ficaria dentro do `TextView`, para ter maior visibilidade do que o layout está criando, você pode ativar nas opções de desenvolvedor a opção: `Limites de layout`, com essa opção você consegue ver todos os componentes da tela, ou ver pelo `blueprint` no editor de layout do android studio.